# When new answers are loaded inline, they appear in the wrong place

Tags: bug, user-interface, pagination

After I answered [a question that's been getting a lot of answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update), I got a notification that yet another answer had been added. After I clicked on the link, the new answer was loaded *above* the paging UI:

[image: New answer loaded over the paging UI]

Obviously this is both rare and trivial. It's only worth fixing if the change is immediately obvious.

Comment: Is this specific to the new mSO design? I kinda assume not, that would be weird, but just to clarify.

Comment: @Undo: Good question. I assume not, but I haven't tested it elsewhere.

Comment: @Undo - I believe so. That build is chalk full of bugs imo.

Comment: Browser / OS? No repro on Chrome on my Mac (for the same question as you).

Comment: @Laura: Chrome and Mac. Maybe it's unique to me because the answer _under_ the page UI is my own? Or maybe it's because I'm sorting by "active"?